# An exception happened in constructor of class com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel

Tags: android

I am working on an application. I am trying to restore the state, when I return to the application from putting it into the background. I got an exception for which I currently have no idea why it happened. So, I decided to post here, to hopefully have someone spot what I am unable to see currently.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.mgr/com.mgr.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception happened in constructor of class com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel
```

This can be traced back to: `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory`

```
internal fun <T : ViewModel?> newInstance(
    modelClass: Class<T>,
    constructor: Constructor<T>,
    vararg params: Any
): T {
    return try {
        constructor.newInstance(*params)
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to access $modelClass", e)
    } catch (e: InstantiationException) {
        throw RuntimeException("A $modelClass cannot be instantiated.", e)
    } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
        throw RuntimeException(
            "An exception happened in constructor of $modelClass", e.cause
        )
    }
}
```

---

*More of my own code now:*

**MainViewModel.tk**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel()
{
    companion object {
        const val UI_MENU_STATE = "ui.menu.state"
    }

    init {
        savedStateHandle.get<Boolean>(UI_MENU_STATE)?.let {
                m -> onMenuStateChange(m);
        }
    }

    private var m_title by mutableStateOf("")
    private var displayMenu by mutableStateOf( false)

    var tosVisible by mutableStateOf( false)
        internal set

    fun updateTitleState(title: String){
        m_title = title;
    }

    fun onMenuStateChange(open: Boolean){
        Log.d("App", open.toString());
        displayMenu = open;
        savedStateHandle.set<Boolean>(UI_MENU_STATE, displayMenu);
    }

    fun isMenuOpen(): Boolean {
        return displayMenu;
    }

    fun getTitle(): String { return m_title; }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this)
        )[MainViewModel::class.java]

        setContent {
            MgrTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) { Main(mainViewModel) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**FULL STACK TRACE:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mgr, PID: 11242
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mgr/com.mgr.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception happened in constructor of class com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception happened in constructor of class com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactoryKt.newInstance(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:234)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at com.mgr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel.setDisplayMenu(MainViewModel.kt:54)
        at com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel.onMenuStateChange(MainViewModel.kt:40)
        at com.mgr.ui.viewmodels.MainViewModel.<init>(MainViewModel.kt:24)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactoryKt.newInstance(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:228)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:133) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153) 
        at com.mgr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

---

**EDIT: Passing into a separate** `@Composable` **method.**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Main(viewModel: MainViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()) {
```

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the entire stack trace. There should be one or more "Caused by" stanzas that will tell us more about the root cause of your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare, posted full stack trace. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

You can try moving your `init {}` block to be after you declare `displayMenu`. I am not confident that this will work, but it is worth a try.

If that does not help, then you may need to postpone your use of the `SavedStateHandle` until sometime when the `MutableState` is ready for use.